# Garbage value in merge sort

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

While writing a simple merge sort algorithm I faced a weird problem.

The code is working fine until I am adding any printf() statement before return statement of mergeSort function.
If I remove that printf() statement then garbage value is coming in output.

This is happening only when the first element of array to be sorted is largest element.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int* mergeSort(int*,int,int);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10,2,5,6,7,0,3,1,8};
    int i;
    int* a = mergeSort(arr,0,8);

    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);

    printf("\n bye");
    return 0;
}

int* mergeSort(int *arr, int left, int right)
{
    int mid = (left+right)/2;
    int len = right-left+1;
    int* result = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(len)), *arr1,*arr2;
    int i=0;
    int l1,l2,r1,r2;
    l2 = mid+1;

    i = 0;
    if(len < 3)
    {
        if(len == 2)
        {
            if(arr[left] > arr[right])
            {
                result[0] = arr[right];
                result[1] = arr[left] ;
            }
            else
            {
                result[0] = arr[left];
                result[1] = arr[right];
            }

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result[0] = arr[left];
            return result;
        }
    }

    arr1 = mergeSort(arr,left,mid);
    arr2 = mergeSort(arr,l2,right);
    l1 = 0;
    l2 = 0;
    r1 = mid-left;
    r2 = right-l2;

    while(i<len)
    {
        if(l1 > r1)
        {
            // put rest of arr2 in result and return
            while(i<len)
            {
                result[i] = arr2[l2];
                i++;
                l2++;

            }
                free(arr1);
                free(arr2);
                return result;
        }
        else if(l2 > r2)
        {
            // put rest of arr1 in result and return
            while(i<len)
            {
                result[i] = arr1[l1];
                i++;
                l1++;

            }

                free(arr1);
                free(arr2);
                return result;
        }

        if(arr1[l1] > arr2[l2])
        {
            result[i] = arr2[l2];
            l2++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            result[i] = arr1[l1];
            l1++;
            i++;
        }       
    }

    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);

    //printf("Stackoverflow"); // I have to add this to make it work
    return result;
}
```

If I comment the third last then the code will return garbage value.

**Why is this problem occurring ? And how can I resolve it ?**

Here is a link to the screenshot of outputs I am getting without/with printf("Stackoverflow") statement : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPqyd.jpg

Note : It seems like it is working in other developer's system, I am using gcc 3.4.2 in mingw32.

Answer : It seems like it it happening due to logical error in my code as Matt McNabb &  Mahonri Moriancumer pointed out.

Comment: `<malloc.h>`? Better take `<stdlib.h>`, it's standard.

Comment: Without / with printf("Stackoverflow"); i am getting the same output! any other specific details?

Comment: In the blocks `// put rest of arr2 in result and return` and `// put rest of arr1 in result and return`, there is a `return` statement at the bottom of each `while()` loop; which make these 'non-loops'.  Is that intended?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Yes it is intended.

Comment: @Sathish Nothing right now, but I am trying to get some more information. Is it showing correct output ?

Comment: @Deduplicator Thank you sir, I'll take care of that from next time :)

Comment: @RohitRawat, then you are using `while()` statements where `if()` statements would suffice?  Interesting (but logically confusing).

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Oh no ! Thats a blunder. Thank you for pointing it out. The return statement was supposed to be out of loop.

Comment: I don't see any garbage value in the output when I run the code.  Can you show an example of what you see?

Comment: @MysticXG I have added a link in question. You can check it. I am using gcc 3.4.2 in mingw32. It seems like this problem is occurring only in my system and if that's the case then I am more interested to know the root cause of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 = 0; 
l2 = 0; 
r1 = mid-left; 
r2 = right-l2;
```

should be:

```
r1 = mid-left; 
r2 = right-l2;
l1 = 0; 
l2 = 0;
```

[Not working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cad4239d145b390)
[Working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8247cfe7e3f67417)

The different behaviour seen between implementations would depend on what garbage was after you ran off the end of `arr2`.

I highly recommend that you use readable variable names (not `l1`!) and comment your code to indicate what it was doing, and don't re-use variables. Declare variables when needing them. You would have spotted the problem sooner if the code had been:

```
int arr2_starts_at = mid + 1;
// ....

int arr1_iter = 0;
int arr2_iter = 0;

// One less than the number of items in each part
int arr1_iter_limit = mid - left;
int arr2_iter_limit = right - arr2_iter;   // should be arr2_starts_at
```

In fact you would have put the definitions of `l1` and `l2` after the calculations of `arr1_length` etc. so you never would have had the problem.

I'd also prefer using the length that you are iterating over, instead of the index you are stopping at, e.g.

```
// no comment required, "arr1_length" says it all
int arr1_length = mid - left + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt McNabb this has resolved that problem of garbage value but do you have any idea of why it was working with printf in my code and not without it ?

Comment: When undefined behaviour happens anything can happen. Possibly the phantom entries off the end of the array all happened to contain values that did not affect the sort order in that case.